# Batch file to multiple rename file name in a folder with a criteria for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, rename

I use Windows 7 64 bit and I have a list of files with with the name of the file composed of

author - album name - name of the song

I need all the names of the files to become

author - name of the song - album name

the file extension (.mp3, .mp4, .mpeg) should not be changed and should be left as in the original

```
My old file name:
author - album name - name of the song
Céline Dion - Loved Me Back to Life - Save Your Soul
Céline Dion - Loved Me Back to Life - Unfinished Songs
Michael Jackson - Bad - Dirty Diana
Michael Jackson - Thriller - Baby Be Mine


My new file name
author - name of the song - album name
Céline Dion - Save Your Soul - Loved Me Back to Life
Céline Dion - Unfinished Songs - Loved Me Back to Life
Michael Jackson - Dirty Diana - Bad
Michael Jackson - Baby Be Mine - Thriller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tryed more Powershell script that do not work i find this solution with simple batch file

Powershell codes seems not working.

```
@Echo Off&SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("* - * - *.*")Do (Set "BaseNameBefore=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=?" %%I In (
        "!BaseNameBefore: - =?!")Do EndLocal&If "%%L" == "" If Not %%K == "" (
        Ren "%%G" "%%I - %%K - %%J%%~xG"))
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is an excellent choice for this instead of a batch file. I make no guarantees with this script--be sure to backup your folder as the names will be rearranged automatically. Additionally, this does not do any error handling--it will be imperfect if a file is misnamed or does not follow the naming convention you describe.

```
Set-Location C:\pathHere\

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    $artist,$album,$song = $_.BaseName.Split(" - ")
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($artist + " - " + $song + " - "  + $album + $_.Extension)
}
```

Comment: Hi i have a problem what i can set the complete path of the folder with files to rename ? The powershell file must be saved in another folder otherwise rename the .ps1 file too. Help me to add the path with file to rename in powershell code please, thanks

Comment: @cicoria I added a top command to set the working directory if you are using this as a saved script. I personally was just running it from the terminal after manually navigating to the folder.

Comment: I tried but seems not working, my files was not renamed, can you try wth a test folder and test files please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If bulk processing is needed, but a batch file isn't absolutely required, two GUI driven utilities come to mind:

1. [MediaMonkey](https://www.mediamonkey.com/download/) can be installed or run in a portable mode without
   installation. It's intended for persistent management of a media
   library and will also set ID3 tags, but could be used once.

   - If the files are already tagged, MediaMonkey will automatically infer the Artist, Album, and Track

     - If the files are not tagged, auto-tag from the filename (Alt+Q), using the following format: `<Artist> - <Album> - <Title>`
   - Rename the file from the tags (Ctrl+R), using the Move and rename option, based on this format: `<Artist> - <Title> - <Album>`
2. [Métamorphose2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/file-folder-ren/files/Metamorphose%202/) has to be installed, but can make the desired
   change using some regular expresions and a swap renamer.

   - Swap this, in between this text:

     - `[^\W\d]-[^\W\d]+-` and this text:`-[^\W\d]`
   - with this, in between this text:

     - `[^\W\d]-` and this text: `-[^\W\d]`
   - Ensure that Evaluate as a regular expression is ticked for both.

Either application can preview the change before it is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this PowerShell script, and it's better to run it with PowerShell 7, you can download it at GitHub. (Otherwise it may not be working.)

```
$path=$args[0]
$extension=$args[1]
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse -Include $extension -File | Foreach-Object {
    $name=$_.BaseName.Split(" - ")
    if ($name.Count -eq 3) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($name[0]+" - "+$name[2]+" - "+$name[1]+$_.Extension)
    }
}
```

Save it as rensong.ps1, and run it by cd to its location first, then run it like this:

```
.\rensong.ps1 "C:\Path\to\Folder" "*.ext1,*.ext2,*.ext3"
```

For example:

```
.\rensong.ps1 "C:\Users\Estranger\Music" "*.mp3,*.mp4,*.mpeg"
```

You can use more than three extensions, just follow the format.